# How can i test Perl code for DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)

Tags: perl, dry

For Python, we could use something like [Python Code Clone Detector](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578206-python-code-clone-detector-dont-repeat-yourself/)

But i just could not find anything for Perl.
With reference to DRY,  [Catalyst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalyst_%28software%29) mentions that its build on DRY principle. and if it is i would imagine some tool might have been used to verify that claim.

Furthermore does Perl promote DRY or not ? I know for sure it promotes repeat Others by using CPAN.

Comment: I've been thinking about such tools for Perl lately. I haven't done anything about it though.

Comment: I don't know of an existing utility, but [PPI](https://metacpan.org/module/PPI) would be where to start if you wanted to write one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You probably mean "Perl promotes 'do not repeat others' by providing CPAN", and that is certainly true.

However, DRY is more of a general programming principle (write many specialized, small functions that can be parametrized properly by their arguments instead of writing monolithic functions that "do it all") than a language feature. You can write DRY-compliant code in C++, Python, Perl, Ruby, C and most others. Some languages require more boilerplate, some less.

Perl definitely allows for small functions with few boilerplate by providing concise language constructs.

I don't know of tools detecting non-DRY code for Perl, though.

Comment: Is this related to Perl 5.x not having  Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) ?

Comment: No, it isn't.  "Having an AST" is *also* not a language feature.